# Does setting A=B somehow mess with B? (all vectors) C++

Tags: c++, vector, copying

Im making a function that matches two vectors of strings. As a part of that function I need to make a copy of the vectors. I would like to do that in the beginning of the function, but somehow it makes my functions crash if I do so. This is how I would like to set up the function

```
vector<string> match(vector<string> & u,vector<string> & v){

// I would like to define these first, but that crashes my function
    vector<string> u1=u;
    vector<string> v1=v;
    u1.erase(u1.begin());
    v1.erase(v1.begin());
// I would like to define these first, but that crashes my function

    if(u.size()==0){
        return u;
    }
    if(v.size()==0){
        return v;
    }

    if(u.at(0)==v.at(0)){
        vector<string>result=match(u1,v1);
        result.insert(result.begin(),u[0]);
        return result;
    }

    if(match(u,v1)>=match(u1,v)){
        vector<string>result= match(u,v1);
        return result;
    }

    else{
        return match(u1,v);
    }
}
```

A simple switch does however make the function work, which I dont understand why

```
vector<string> match(vector<string> & u,vector<string> & v){

//Putting these if statements first makes the function work
    if(u.size()==0){
        return u;
    }
    if(v.size()==0){
        return v;
    }
//Putting these if statements first makes the function work

    vector<string> u1=u;
    vector<string> v1=v;
    u1.erase(u1.begin());
    v1.erase(v1.begin());



    if(u.at(0)==v.at(0)){
        vector<string>result=match(u1,v1);
        result.insert(result.begin(),u[0]);
        return result;
    }

    if(match(u,v1)>=match(u1,v)){
        vector<string>result= match(u,v1);
        return result;
    }

    else{
        return match(u1,v);
    }
}
```

Comment: copy constructor issue??

Comment: What is the high-level goal of this code?  Is it to return a vector that contains items that are in both vectors?  If so, then `std::set_intersection` could have been used instead of all of this code.  Using `std::set_intersection` would not have you run afoul of the invalid iterators that @VittorioRomeo pointed out in his answer.

Comment: Sort of, but the individual items placement seems to have an effect on the output as well. I haven't been told what the overall goal is, just a list of conditions from which to recursively generate an output.

Comment: If this is just a matching, and return a vector of the matches [this is an example of using set_intersection](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e8331b7e125ad7d).  The bottom line is that if you're writing hand-crafted `for` loops to do something that seems it has been done before many times over, there is a good chance that there is one or more STL algorithm functions that do the job without writing those `for` loops.

Answer (score 7):

```
vector<string> u1=u;
u1.erase(u1.begin());
```

If `u.size() == 0` then `u1.begin() == u1.end()`. Calling `vector<string>::erase` on an iterator that doesn't point to an existing element is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Ahh, ofcause. I didn't take that scenario into consideration. Thank you